# Why is `<newline>` === `\n` true but `\r\n` === `\n` is false?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

There are different control character/sequence of them which represent(s) a new line with regard to different platforms. In accordance with the rules of template literals interpretation, under whatever platform JavaScript code is running, a new line within the literal must be normalized to line feed (`\n`). In terms of the [spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-static-semantics-tv-and-trv), `<CR><LF> and <CR> LineTerminatorSequences are normalized to <LF> for both TV and TRV.`

So it returns true:

```
`foo
boo` === `foo\nboo`
```

However, this logic is not applicable when we explicitly put the different representations of new line:

```
`foo\nboo` === `foo\r\nboo` // false
`foo\nboo` === `foo\rboo` // false
```

Why does JavaScript distinguish these two cases? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Because different characters are not the same? Surely you can see that same thing if we did `"ab" === "acb"`.

Comment: because \n and \r are not the same????

Comment: Wait, if you're quoting the standard, why did you omit literally the next sentence after your quote: "*An explicit EscapeSequence is needed to include a <CR> or <CR><LF> sequence.*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full text of the note in [the ECMAScript specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-static-semantics-tv-and-trv) is as follows:

> TV excludes the code units of LineContinuation while TRV includes them. `<CR><LF>` and `<CR>` LineTerminatorSequences are normalized to `<LF>` for both TV and TRV. **An explicit EscapeSequence is needed to include a `<CR>` or `<CR><LF>` sequence.**

Emphasis added.

This means that `` `\r\n` `` and `` `\r` `` are preserved. Therefore, the code works as expected:

```js
console.log([...`\r\n`]);
console.log([...`\r`]);
console.log([...`
`]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

```
'\u000A\u000D' === '\n\r'`
```

since `\n` & `\r` are simply aliases for given control characters.

Also you can see normalisation to LF happening in

```
eval("`\n\r`") === "\n\n"
```

each char becomes LF, and

```
eval("`\r\n`") === "\n"
```

CR+LF becomes LF.
But again, this is only for the source *parsing* stage (hence the `eval`), using it explicitly in literals or while reading strings from external resources works without "hidden" normalisation, so comparisons will work as expected.